# C++, Apply template pattern to function selectively

Tags: c++, templates

I have a class that can either be constructed by arguments of "ordinary" types, int, string, etc., or that can be constructed by a couple of different 'special' types invented by a coworker.

The 'special' types have the same signature, but aren't in a parent-child relationship.

So the code I have now looks something like:

```
class my_nifty_class {
  public:
  // "ordinary" constructor
  template <class T> my_nifty_class(T) {some generic code}

  // "special" constructors
  my_nifty_class(my_first_clever_class) {
    some clever code
  }
  my_nifty_class(my_second_clever_class) {
    the identical clever code
  }
```

In order to avoid duplicating some clever code (and opening myself up to the risk of not always duplicating it right), I would like to replace this with

```
class my_nifty_class {
  public:
  // "ordinary" constructor
  template <class T> my_nifty_class(T) {some generic code}

  // "special" constructors
  template <class clever_class> my_nifty_class(clever_class) {
    /**** I need template magic somewhere around here ****/
    some clever code
  }
```

But -- I don't know the template magic to put in there, or if there is any such magic to be had.  I know I could do it if I were declaring classes -- but I'm declaring functions, so I'm kinda stuck.

Comment: What do you want the constructor to do?

Comment: So you want some type to run on one constructor, and the others run on another?

Comment: Code example is incomplete. It would be good to show what you are trying to attempt. What is the "magic" you are referring to?  What are you exactly stuck with?

Comment: @KaenbyouRin Yes.

Comment: @Tagger5926 The magic I'm referring to is whatever I need to have the second version of the constructor only run on the two classes I specify, while the first runs on everything else.  If I knew what it was, I wouldn't be asking.

Comment: Oh wait, is your problem that since you already templated the constructor for POD types you are having trouble having another templated constructor for your complex data types?

Answer (score 3):

You want `std::enable_if`, and you want some compile-time property of your special classes that other classes don't have.

```
template <class T, class S = std::enable_if_t<!is_my_special_v<T>>>
my_nifty_class(T) {some generic code}

template <class T, class S = std::enable_if_t<is_my_special_v<T>>, bool = true>
my_nifty_class(T) {some special code}
```

(The dummy template parameter is needed to make the two templates distinct)

Another method is to have just one constructor and use the special selector inside.

```
template <class T>
my_nifty_class(T) {
   if constexpr(is_my_special_v<T>)
     some special code
   else
     some generic code
}
```

How do you write is_my_special_v? It is just a template with the value of false, with specialisations for your special types with the value of true.

```
template<class> constexpr bool is_my_special_v = false;
template<> constexpr bool is_my_special_v<MySpecialType1> = true:
// ...
```

If all your special classes have some member name that is unlikely to occur in non-special classes, you can use that in order to write just one specialisation of is_my_special_v total instead of one per special class. Search for "c++ member detection", lots of material out there.

Finally, if this is the only place where your special types are indeed special, you can skip 
is_my_special_v altogether and just check directly.

```
template <class T>
my_nifty_class(T) {
   if constexpr(std::is_same_v<T, MySpecialType1> ||
         std::is_same_v<T, MySpecialType2> ...)
     some special code
   else
     some generic code
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this looks like the one.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you can use "tag structures" and class template specializations to solve your problem:

```
struct TypeA {};
struct TypeB {};
struct TypeC {};

class Class {
public:
    template<class T> Class(T val) : Class(typename SelectTag<T>::Type{}, val) {}

private:
    struct GenericTag {};
    struct BOrCTag {};

    template<class T> struct SelectTag { using Type = GenericTag; };


    template<class T> Class(GenericTag, T val) { /* do smth */ }
    template<class T> Class(BOrCTag, T val) { /* do smth else */ }
};

template<> struct Class::SelectTag<TypeB> { using Type = BOrCTag; };

template<> struct Class::SelectTag<TypeC> { using Type = BOrCTag; };
```

Comment: Yes, I'm doing exactly that.  But where you have one thing that takes TypeB, I want one thing that takes TypeB or TypeC, but not int, float, or TypeA.

Comment: @TimWescott, I've just updated my solution. There are vast of approaches to solve your problem. This is possibly one of them.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my go at the answer. You will just share a generic constructor for all types. And handle the logic within the constructor using `std::is_pod` which was introduced in c++11 I believe.

Essentially POD (plain old data) types such as; int, float, double, etc. will be handled by one templated function, and any complex/non-trivial data types will be handled by your other templated function.

```
class my_nifty_class {
  public:
  template<class T> handle_pod_type(T value)
  { /* Code to handle POD data types */ }

  template<class SpecialType> handle_special_type(SpecialType value)
  { /* Code to handle complex data types */ }

  template <class T> my_nifty_class(T value) {
     if( std::is_pod<T>::value ) {
        handle_pod_type(value);
     }
     else {
        handle_special_type(value);
     }
  }

}
```

Also take note of what `is_pod` is doing and what classifies a POD type in C++11.

Comment: std::string is not a pod.

Comment: could check with is string but not too sure about other edge cases